# For each new row inserted, add value + 1 to column

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that inserts a new row every time I press the command button. However, I would like to alter the code so that every time I press the command button, a value, starting with "1" is inserted into Column D (in the row where the new row is created). When the button is pressed again, and a new row is inserted again, "2" would appear in D10 for instance if the row prior was inserted in row 9.

Currently I have code that just adds the new row, plus pastes some formatting/values that I need.

```
`Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRsp As Long
On Error Resume Next

lRow = Selection.Row()
lRsp = MsgBox("Insert New row above " & lRow & "?", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If lRsp <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

Rows(lRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Rows(lRow + 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Paste formulas and conditional formatting in new row created
Rows(lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone
i = 1
Range("D9").Value = i


End Sub`
```

Comment: `Range("D" & lRow).Value = Range("D" & lRow).Value +1` ?

Comment: Yes, in a sense. Where would I put this

Comment: I recommend you remove `On Error Resume Next`.  It is hiding the fact that you are trying to `PasteSpecial` after you have exited `CutCopyMode`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRsp As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    lRow = Selection.Row()
    lRsp = MsgBox("Insert New row above " & lRow & "?", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If lRsp <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    Rows(lRow).Copy 'REMOVED SELECT
    Rows(lRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'REMOVED SELECT
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Paste formulas and conditional formatting in new row created
    Rows(lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone
    'i = 1 'REMOVED
    'Range("D9").Value = i 'REMOVED
    cells(lrow,4).value = Application.max(columns(4))+1 'ADDED

End Sub
```

Also, try and go back through this and remove (where applicable) `Select` and `Selection`... see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)